# JS variable binding in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want to do some data binding with Polymer. I defined a custom element:

```
<dom-module id="my-voltage">
  <template is="auto-binding">
    <div class="circle">{{volts}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyVoltage extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return "my-voltage";
      }
      static get properties() {
  return {
    volts: {
      type: String
    },
  }
}
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }
    customElements.define(MyVoltage.is, MyVoltage);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Now, I want to dynamically get the `volts` to be bound to a JS variable. So the JS is like:

```
  volt = JSON.parse(httpGet('some-api-call'));
  voltage = volt.value.toString();
```

and I want `volts` to display the value of `voltage`. I'm trying `document.getElementById("volt").setAttribute("volts", voltage);`, but I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null" at the attribute assignment. What's the proper way to do this in polymer?

I do have the element in html:

```
  <my-voltage id="volt" class="circle" volts="-1"></my-voltage>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using Polymer 2.0+. I've only been using previous versions.

Anyway, so you want to assign data to a child element? The problem here is that during the "ready" method, there are no guarantees that the child elements have loaded. If you would like to do something more advanced, like doing a form validation, you have to create an interval that loops until the child element actually exists.

```
var voltElement = {};

var intervalId = setInterval((function() {
  voltElement = this.$.volt;

  if (voltElement) {
    //enter code here
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}).bind(this));
```

The *.bind(this)* is only there so you can use the correct scope inside the anonymous function in setInterval.

However, the problem isn't that complex for you. What you can instead do is to create a property variable and assign that to the voltage property in the *my-voltage* element when it's created.

```
<my-voltage id="volt" class="circle" volts="[[voltage]]"></my-voltage>
```

---

```
volt = JSON.parse(httpGet('some-api-call'));
this.set('voltage', volt.value.toString());
```

Using *this.set()* makes Polymer send an event to elements using that variable if the variable has been already set on beforehand, like been given a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Polymer's components you should use native polymer operators.
So, next js code should be rewritten via polymer's operators.

```
document.getElementById("volt").setAttribute("volts", voltage);
```

In *Polymer 1.9.1*, this line will have next view:

```
this.$.volt.set("volts", voltage);
```

or

```
this.$$('#volt').set("volts", voltage);
```

In *Polymer 2.0* or *3.0*, you could use next syntax:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#volt').set("volts", voltage);
```

More info about the node finding in *Polymer 1.9.1*, you can find there:
https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding

More examples with *this.shadowRoot.querySelector*, you can find there: https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/dom-template